# Will keras reuses weights if I define model in a function when take keras as interface to TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am not sure if the weights of layers would be reused if I define the layers in a function and call it outside, e.g.

```
def forward(x):
    y = Dense(128, activation='tanh')(x)
    y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)
    return y
```

I define the model in function `forward`. And then use it as interface of tensorflow like:

```
y1 = forward(x1)
y2 = forward(x2)
```

Will layers' weight be reused?

Answer (score 1):

The weights will not be the same. When you write `y = Dense(128,...)(x)` inside a function, this creates a new instance layer every time you call the function. So y1 and y2 will not share weights in your example.

However if you wanted to make them share weights, you can create the layer instances outside of the function , the function will only reuse the same layer. So the weights will be shared. This will work in your case :

```
layer_dense1 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')
layer_dense2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

def forward(x):
    y = layer_dense1(x)
    y = layer_dense2(y)
    return y

y1 = forward(x1)
y2 = forward(x2)
```

This will work only if `x1` and `x2` have the same shape. Indeed, when you first link `layer_dense1` at your first call of forward, it will set `layer_dense1.input_shape` to the shape of x1. If you call it on a layer that has a different shape, it will throw an error at your face :-)